# How to change touch priority on overlapping sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, sprite, overlapping

Is there any way to change the touch priority for cocos2d iOS sprites? What I have are multiple cards on the screen and they are arrayed in an arc, just like it would when you hold them in your hands. So in this setup, they overlap, and I need to recognize on which card the touch was made. I could measure the coordinates of each vertex of cards and determine the visible area of a card and then check if the touch was made inside that area (couldn't I?) but I thought there would be an easier way to deal with this, say changing the touch priority? Which means that the card closest to the screen would have the highest priority and it'll keep decreasing along the way into the background, so that even if the touch was made on 2 sprites at once (the above and below one), it would be registered only on the sprite with higher priority.

Reading on the internet only revealed ways to change the priority for a sprite and layer so that it defines whether the touch was made on the layer or the sprite, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, by default you get exactly that behavior, the sprites closer (on the z ax) to you have priority. However, I think they pass down the event to the ones behind them as well. So, what i think you need to do is to eat the event when it gets to any of your sprites. To do that, just return NO when overwriting the "touchBegin" method. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I did something similar, I just returned TRUE in touchBegan when a touch has been detected so that the touch will not be boiled down further because the function would have to end as soon as the return statement is executed.